# Unable to install TestFlight Access Profile (iOS)

Tags: ios, ios6, testflight

Since upgrading to iOS 6 I have been unable to install the "TestFlight Access" profile, and my clients running 6.0 are experiencing the same issues. I have googled the issue but I am not finding any results.

The error message is just after you enter your device password and reads:

"Profile Installation Failed
A network error has occurred"

I have verified I have a good network connection, and the error is happening at multiple physical locations (different service providers and internet access)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just had the same problem with our build and one of our testers found this solution:

" advise people to go to settings > general > profiles and remove their profile and then clear cookies / cache, reboot the phone and it should work"

Make sure to remove the TestFlight WebClip profile as well.

Hope this helps!

Ryan

Comment: Fixed. Thanks! Going to Settings > general > profiles and remove their profile and then clear cookies / cache were enough. No reboot needed.

Comment: I didn't even need to clear cookies and cache. Just killing the existing WebClip profile made me able to proceed.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on iOS 7 beta 3. Strangely, it worked yesterday.